# change the image of a div-a if the content in div-b equals to this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not have much knowledge of Javascript and Jquery and here is what i wanna do.

I have this concept of having 2 divs and

if the inner html of div-a = Canada then change the image in div-b to image1

else if the inner html of div-a = USA then change the image in div-b to image2

else hide div-b

and the function should work on document.load as well as onclick when div-a changes.

thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: No I had tried some stuff which didnt work and i had to get rid of it as it was on the live website. Now its back to scratch :)

Comment: Then I'd try and create a JS fiddle (jsfiddle.net) and work in there and then post the fiddle so we can all look at it without doing it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63UK2/2/)

Html

```
<div class="div-a">Canada</div>
<div class="div-b"><img src=""></div>

<a class="link" href="#">USA</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Canada</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Wohoo</a>
```

JS

```
function loadImg(str) {
    switch(str) {
        case 'Canada':
             $('.div-b img').show().attr('src', 'http://ec.europa.eu/education/images/flags/canada.gif');
             break;
        case 'USA': 
             $('.div-b img').show().attr('src', 'http://ec.europa.eu/education/images/flags/usa.gif');
             break;
        default: 
            $('.div-b img').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    loadImg($('.div-a').text());

    $('.link').click(function() {
          $('.div-a').text($(this).text());
          loadImg($(this).text());
    });
});
```